# What type for virtual function does a class have when a member destructor runs?

Tags: c++, virtual

I have this situation:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B { virtual void f() { std::cout << "base"; } };

struct A {
  ~A() {
      b->f();
  }

  B *b;
};


struct Bd : B { 
  Bd():a{this}{ }
  ~Bd() { }
  virtual void f() { std::cout << "derived"; } 

  A a;
};

int main() {
  Bd d;
}
```

Is it guaranteed that this prints "derived"?

Comment: I reckon it will either call `B::f`, or invoke undefined behaviour. The lifetime of an object formally ends [when its destructors begins](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime), so when `A::~A` calls `b->f();`, `b`'s derived part is already dead.

Comment: also have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092933/calling-virtual-function-from-destructor)

Comment: @Quentin that quote doesn't look right at all. You definitely can access object from its own destructor, which is at odds with the ban to access it once its lifetime ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[class.cdtor]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#4):

> Member functions, including virtual functions ([class.virtual]), can
>   be called during construction or destruction ([class.base.init]). When
>   a virtual function is called directly or indirectly from a constructor
>   or from a destructor, **including during the construction or destruction
>   of the class's non-static data members,** and the object to which the
>   call applies is the object (call it `x`) under construction or
>   destruction, the function called is the final overrider in the
>   constructor's or destructor's class and not one overriding it in a
>   more-derived class.

"The class" at issue here is `Bd`, so it should call the final overrider of `f()` in `Bd`, and print `derived`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to look it up now, but the rule is that a virtual call on an object whose destructor is running goes to the class whose destructor is currently running. So in the destructor for `Bd`, the destructor for `a` runs, and the call `b->f()` calls `Bd::f`.

If `a` had been a member of `B` instead of `Bd`, the call would go to `B::f`, because the destructor of `a` would run from `B`'s destructor.

If you prefer to think of mechanisms (I generally don't), think in terms of the vtable; on entry into a destructor, the code sets the vtable pointer to point to the vtable belonging to the destructor that's running.