# C++ ( Classes and pointers)

Tags: c++, class, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
    virtual void method() {std::cout << "from Base" << std::endl;}
public:
    virtual ~Base() {method();}
    void baseMethod() {method();}
};

class A : public Base {
    void method() {std::cout << "from A" << std::endl;}
public:
    ~A() {method();}
};

int main(void) {
    Base* base = new A;
    base->baseMethod();
    delete base;
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand why the output of this code is:
from A
from A
from Base

Technically it should only print "from A " only.

Comment: Don't call virtual methods from the destructor. See this excellent answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092933/calling-virtual-function-from-destructor)

Answer (score 1):

Its called [Upcast](https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php), take a look at the example in the link for more information. The first "from A" occurs when you execute:

```
 base->baseMethod();
```

The second "from A" when the destructor of A is called, and the "from Base" is printed when the destructor of Base is called.

Answer (score 0):

base is object of type A,
So base->baseMethod() will call A's implementation of virtual method method(), 
"from A" is printed, 
method() is called from the d'tors of A and base,
When deleting an object in cpp it's d'tor is called and it's base class d'tor is called right after (the opposit  when creating an object) so :
"from A" 
"from base" 
is printed.

Answer (score 0):

When we call `base->baseMethod()` it calls the `Base::baseMethod` as it not overriden by `class A`. `baseMethod` calls `method` function, as `base` is pointer of `class A`, it calls the `A::method` as it is overriden. Even though the method is private it follows the polymorphic behaviour.

When `delete base` is executed, first destructor of derived class is called because `Base class` destructor is virtual. Derived class destructor call it own `method` function. If we do not had virtual destructor then destructor of derived was not called and hence you have seen only one `from A` as output apeend by from base

After that it calls the base class destructor and this calls the `method function` of `Base class` only as derived class is already destructed.